# my question is closed with an invalid(?) reason

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question][1] yesterday. The question is closed as it's claimed to be 'opinion-based'. Plus, history tag becomes useless.

There is not a biased or subjective opinion in this question. Do show me, please, which part of the question is 'opinion based'.

> Opinion-based - Discussions focused on diverse opinions can be great, but they just don't fit our format well. Music stack exchange defines it as follows:

*This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.
It’s often possible to rewrite opinion-based questions to focus on a more fact-based line of questioning. If you see a way to do this, consider editing the question.*

This question can definitely be answered with facts; a music history enthusiast can perfectly do; hence the **history** tag.

Also, if this is considered opinion based; most of the questions regarding harmony must be closed as one usually can't provide an answer regarding western harmony without interpreting it.

For instance, if a composer during these eras wrote an article and claimed him/herself as elitis; that would be an answer. But closing this question claiming that it is opinion-based which is not is simply preventing me from reaching an answer.

In the question I started with quoting a reliable source, I provided a link leads to the source, in the paragraph about minimalism I paraphrased articles on Minimalism, I again expressed a teacher's view to provide a reason why I'm asking this question and you can find this view on many articles on 'tonality'.

**Please do show me which part of the question is opinion based.**

Comment: Please do not link to external sites to respond.

Comment: You are taking most of the question you list out of context and the few that are not are new and could be closed. The site is not perfect and things will slip though the cracks, but  you are approaching this in a manner that isn't the most constructive. People have explained why your question was closed and how to improve it. A lot of this feels directed at the users of the site themselves and that's not a good path to go down when trying to site policies.

Comment: @Dom Dear Dom, I already realised it's a dead-end and accepted Richard's kind and explanatory answer as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you, first of all, for asking. I think too often a question gets closed, someone gets angry, there's name-calling, and it becomes a bad experience for everyone. It's always best when these issues are brought to Meta and everyone approaches this in a respectful way.

My rationale for closing was two-fold: (first) the premise of the question was based on an opinion (*some people* thought these composers were elitist, but others thought they were not), which means that (second) *two diametrically opposed answers to your question, as currently written, would be correct*. In other words, there are perfectly suitable answers to your question that say "yes" and others that say "no," *and both could be equally valid*. If two opposite answers to a question are both correct, then that question is better fit for a discussion-based format rather than ours.

I would also invite you to reconsider what makes a question opinion-based. In the help center, we have [some thoughts](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on what constitutes "constructive subjective questions"; they:

- inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
- tend to have long, not short, answers
- have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
- invite sharing experiences over opinions
- insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
- are more than just mindless social fun

[When to use 8va in musical notation?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/90907/21766), which you cite as an opinion-based question, is to me a perfect example of a question *where experience in the field clearly leads to one preferred solution*. The optimal answer is not "whenever you want," but rather one based on experience and practicality, making this a good fit for our format.

As Todd has mentioned in his responses to you, there are objective questions related to what you're asking: "Why were modernist composers at the start of the twentieth century considered by some to be elitist?" could be one of them. But as your question is currently stated, it's unfortunately not a good fit for our site.

Answer (score 4):

I think it’s very unlikely anyone has ever written down anything like, "I’m a modernist composer and an elitist".

Genre alone is somewhat subjective. Not everyone will agree on what makes a composer a modernist. Sometimes composers have labeled themselves with a genre, but I think this is rare enough that it’s hard to base an objective answer on it.

Elitism is also subjective. Unlike genre (most of the time), elitism is almost always seen as a negative quality. Therefore it is very unlikely that a person would see themselves as elitist, because such a person would then want to change and therefore no longer be elitist. So it’s even less likely that any composers in question have called themselves elitist.

Even if we consider the question differently, as in we view it as asking if any composers have admitted to being both modernist and elitist, it’s too broad. There’s too many potential composers to sift through. If you change the question to be about a single composer and adjust the wording to be more objective, then I would consider it on topic. For example, "Did Charles Ives ever discuss whether he considers himself to be both modernist and elitist?" Is an objectively verifiable music history question with a narrow scope.

Your assertions about the appropriateness of your question do not change the content of the question nor its appropriateness. It doesn’t do you or anyone else any good to simply say, "but my question is not opinion based". I hope what I have written above demonstrates the amount of thought and consideration that I and the other users of this stack go through before we vote to close. We have a responsibility to the entire community to compare what is best for the whole community with what is best for one user (in this case, you). We have struggled to understand how this question might be appropriate for the site and found we could not see a viewpoint where it is on topic. I suggest you struggle to see why it’s **not** considered on-topic by us and then either edit it to make it a better fit or accept its closure.

As I commented on the question, the existence of a history tag and attaching any tag to a question is completely irrelevant to whether the question is on topic.

Related to one of your comments, whether I or anyone else is a "hobbyist" is also irrelevant. Part of the stack exchange model is users who demonstrate they have knowledge of the topic of a stack gain more and more trust and responsibility on that stack as they prove increasing levels of knowledge and responsible use of the stack. That is what our reputation scores represent. Whether we have our knowledge because we were paid to learn it or because we learned it on our own time is not considered important by stack exchange. To me, this is justified because what a person learns and understands is much more important than how they learned it. Technically, Einstein was a "hobbyist" when he wrote the paper that he was later awarded a Nobel prize for. "Hobbyists" all over the world and throughout history have made great discoveries and innovations.

Finally, if you look at my profile, you’ll see that I am and/or have been a paid musician, sound engineer, and music educator. I consider it only a matter of time before I’m a paid composer or orchestrator. I have been paid for string arrangements but that’s not in my profile. I’m also currently a student of music composition at George Mason University which required both an audition and portfolio review. I don’t think many people would agree that I’m a "hobbyist" when it comes to music. Also, calling people names is not going to help your with your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would vote to reopen if you include several reliable definitions of "modernism," including Grove itself, since you were asking about something you read in Grove.

By the way I understand you may feel pretty frustrated at this point, but please be polite ("hobbyist" assumption!), and for a very long post, please divide it up into clearly marked sections.